# Refresh Custom Table View when coming back to its View Controller

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, tableview

I want to refresh my Table View after inserting data in it.

So what I'm doing is I click a button, the buttons opens another View Controller where I insert the data then press a button to add that data to an array(Object) and then It goes back to the Table View Controller, and here I want to swipe to refresh my Table View.

Here is my code:

[ViewController.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RoiJ.png)
[AddProcessador.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJQBi.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by refreshing your table view by swiping.
But I have two ideas that might work for you.

1. If you have only these two view controllers and you accept that the table view is also reloaded, for example, right at startup (first call of viewDidLoad), this would be a possibility:

   ```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
   ```
2. If you want to refresh the table view only after saving the entries, you could also create a protocol and use it.

   ```
   // Create the protocol
   protocol ReloaderDelegate {
       func reloadTableView()
   }

   // Set up a variable in your AddProcessador view controller
   var delegate: ReloaderDelegate?

   // Set the delegate to a value when you create the AddProcessador instance in the ViewController
   controller = self

   // Now you can call the function in your AddProcessador view controller
   delegate?.reloadTableView()
   ```

As a complete code:

```
protocol ReloaderDelegate {
    func reloadTableView()
}

class AddProcessador: UIViewController {
    
    var delegate: ReloaderDelegate?
    
    // Your IBOutlets
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // ...
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func addClick(_ sender: Any) {
        
        // 1. Add your new processador
        
        // 2. Reload your table view
        delegate?.reloadTableView()
        
        // 3. Go back
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        
    }
    
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, ReloaderDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // ...
    }
    
    
    func reloadTableView() {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func pushAddProcessador() {
        let controller = AddProcessador()
        controller.delegate = self
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
    
}
```

Please excuse me if I have made a mistake somewhere.
I hope I could help you with this somehow.

Comment: thx! this did help on another project I was working thx! (for studying porpuses)

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    
       refreshControl?.addAction(UIAction(handler: { _ in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
       }), for: .primaryActionTriggered)

}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       refreshControl?.endRefreshing() //this can be moved to number of rows in section as well. We just need to tell the control we have data and to stop spinning.
       return 1 
}
```

Comment: Note: I'm calling on the main thread. I'm doing that because it has something to do with the UI, but I'm almost certain this method can be called from a background thread. TableView should already know to reload on the main thread. I only put the dispatch as a safety.